# XSLT Where is the error here?

Tags: xml, xslt

I dont understand where the error is.
I have tried changing the select in the foreach

```
<xsl:for-each select="author/books">
<xsl:sort select="book-title" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
<tr>
<td><xsl:value of  select="book-title"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Well, *what* "error"? The XLST engine should be quite clear on what is wrong: you should be too when telling others about "the error". (That being said, `<xsl:value of` should likely be `<xsl:value-of` so it's even valid XML.)

Comment: It would also be beneficial to see the data source that you're pulling from

Comment: Please don't ask for help resolving errors without telling us the error message. It's hard enough to solve problems when you've got an error message, but solving them without is just masochism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
<xsl:value of  select="book-title"/>
```

There is no XSLT element `xsl:value`, change it to `xsl:value-of` and the error (in that given fragment) will be no more.